# Can the Pokémon in my egg be shiny if I breed it in the hot springs?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

If I put a egg in the "hot springs" in Poké Pelago can the egg still be a shiny when it's hatched? Or does it have to be in the party?

Answer (score 3):

The contents of an egg get determined when you obtain the egg. Where you hatch it doesn't matter, because the likelihood of it being shiny has been calculated when you got the egg.

Unless they adjusted programming and eggs suddenly behave differently in the Poké Pelago hot springs you should be able to get a shiny from an egg just like normal hatching. It might be quicker to run around with a Pokémon with Flame Body though, I've read the egg hatching in the hot springs can take a few days.